# Calculate Power of Double with Double exponent in C#

Tags: c#

I need to calculate `x^y` where both `x` and `y` are Doubles.

I tried using `Math.Pow`:

```
  Double result = Math.Pow(24.69, 2/3);
```

The value of `result` is 1 where it should be 8.4790 ...

Any idea why?

Comment: `2/3` is integer division, which evaluates to `0`.

Comment: To fix, say `2.0/3.0` instead.

Comment: A single integer in double notation will suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the exponent you are passing in 2 `int`s which is do integer division. So it is doing:

```
Math.Pow(24.69, 0)
```

To fix this use doubles like this:

```
Double result = Math.Pow(24.69, 2.0/3.0);
```